# Check if class has static method

Tags: objective-c

We can easily check if object has a method by using `respondsToSelector:`, but how we do it for static functions in class?

I would like to have something like this:

```
if ([cls classRespondsToSelector:@selector(staticMethodName)]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Objective-C classes are objects too.

```
if ([[myClass class] respondsToSelector:@selector(classMethod)]) {

}
```

Also a small note, these are NOT 'static' methods. That means something specific which doesn't exist in Objective-C. They are class methods.

Comment: Snap! Deleted my identical answer. 28 seconds!

Comment: why would the OP want to check for the existence of a class method given an instance of that class? to call a class method, they need the class object itself, so it would make more sense to be given the class object

Comment: You can always get the class object from an instance, why would that matter?